# Using the Chart.js Gradient Plugin in Angular and typing the chartjs options?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, chart.js

This pure typescript configures a typed chart.js object instance that uses the gradient plugin and Typescript does not produce any linting errors.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-9xhkzc?file=index.ts

However if we try the same thing in Angular:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-7nd716?file=src%2Fmain.ts

Typescript produces linting errors like this:

```
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'gradient' does not exist in type 'ChartDataset<keyof ChartTypeRegistry, (number | [number, number] | Point | BubbleDataPoint | null)[]>'.
```

How do we use the gradient plugin in a typed chart.js configuration instance with Angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In project you provided that works has a dependency "chartjs-plugin-gradient": "^0.6.1" something tells me that it is the case. Because in angular project it is not installed.

And after installing you call this:

```
import gradient from 'chartjs-plugin-gradient';

Chart.register(gradient);
```

Please see the fork:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-pb3dse?file=src%2Fmain.ts

Comment: Oh - Interesting - So registering the gradient modifies the typing ... Neat - Thanks!!