# Building an Angular library containing a provider for chart.js with plugins?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, chart.js, angular-package-format

I'm attempting to build a Angular standalone library for chart.js that will include plugins.

It seems like chart.js modifies the `ChartConfiguration` type when plugins are registered in order to allow for the plugin to be configured.

[If chart.js did not do this linting errors would be produced as shown in this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77996540/using-the-chart-js-gradient-plugin-in-angular-and-typing-the-chartjs-options).

So for example if the gradient plugin is registered like this:

```
import gradient from 'chartjs-plugin-gradient';

Chart.register(...registerables);
Chart.register(gradient);
```

Is there a way to export the modified chart configuration type (`ChartConfiguration`) from an Angular library such that clients can configure chart.js with support for plugins packaged with the provider?

This way clients would be able to import the modified configuration like this:

```
import { ChartConfiguration } from 'angular-chartjs-library';
```

And create chart.js configuration / option instances that are supported by the type namespace in `ChartConfiguration`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if the packaged service registers the `chartjs-plugin-gradient`, clients that want to use it in conjunction with `ChartConfiguration` in order to get typed support for the plugin still need to import `chartjs-plugin-gradient`, because it adds the support via [Typescript's Declaration Merging Feature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html).

So to get typing support for a plugin that is used with Chart.js simply import it like this and the support is added:

```
import gradient from 'chartjs-plugin-gradient';
```

Comment: Naren that looks really promising - However when I try to export the `ChartConfiguration`, Typescript creates the error `'ChartConfiguration' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.ts(2693)` .. Thougths?

Comment: @Ole my mistake please try `export type` or `export interface`

Comment: Oh cool!  That cleared the error.  I'll test it out now - Thanks again!!

Comment: OK - I tried it - and unfortunately it looks like the modified version of `ChartConfiguration` did not get exported ... Because when I try to use the plugin i still generates a linting error ...

Comment: I seems like Chart.js is doing an "In Memory" modification runtime modification to the `ChartConfiguration` and I think this is lost when Angular compiles the library ...

Comment: @Ole OK fine! all the best!

Comment: Yeah I asked the question in a different way and AFAIK Typescript does not know how to compile runtime modifications into a type ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78014759/is-it-possible-to-reexport-typescript-types-modified-at-compile-time

Comment: Naren I changed the answer a little and accepted it.  Kikon pointed out that the typing support is added via typescript type declaration merging, so the updated answer just reflects this.