# Is it possible to reexport typescript types modified through declaration merging?

Tags: javascript, typescript, chart.js, angular-package-format

[In this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78009511/building-an-angular-library-containing-a-provider-for-chart-js-with-plugins) I'm trying to create an Angular library that registers some plugins in chart.js.

```
import gradient from 'chartjs-plugin-gradient';

Chart.register(...registerables);
Chart.register(gradient);
```

And when plugins are imported, it modifies the `ChartConfiguration` type through Typescripts Declaration Merging feature so that the namespace for the type now supports the plugins.

Is there a way export a type that includes the type that has had declaration merging features applied to it?

So for this particular case this new type would include the declaration merge from doing this import.

```
import gradient from 'chartjs-plugin-gradient';
```

Comment: I don't quite understand the question... I see that they suggested you re-export your own `ChartConfiguration` type after registering your plugins. I don't see how compilation would affect this. As long as your consumer imports your `ChartConfiguration` type and not the original one - it should be fine. Perhaps you mean that during compilation your library doesn't produce type definitions? Pretty hard to diagnose without reproduction. Another idea I had on first read is that you might want to do some patching on postinstall, but that's kinda bad.

Comment: The Angular Library uses the Angular Package Format and the Angular CLI to build a standalone library and I tried reexporting the `ChartConfiguration` as `LibraryChartConfiguration` and then using that type instead of the original `ChartConfiguration` type ... However Typescript did not compile in the changes that Chart.js makes to `ChartConfiguration` when plugins are registered ...

Comment: And IIUC ... I don't think it's possible to change a type programmatically and then reexport that type and have another package load the new programmatically modified type ... I think perhaps runtime modifications are OK ... But not compile time modifications ...

Comment: Mm, I see what you mean now. I think it will certainly be a challenge from experience in similar situations. And I don't know much about Angular/ChartJS. But in terms of TypeScript, it does seem like the compiler can produce runtime-aware types, see [example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwDYEMDOa4BVhvgbwCg44wBXAIyQEsE4A7FAW2AC448pr6BzOAHwZkmFYFDgBeOAHJpAbkIBfQoQQR6eOCEkNgAd2y4YACgCUCwqEixE6zSAByzYA+GioAeSgBlGF146IAB0jCwWwaHAOgCMAEwAzBZW0PBqGvCOzq4iYoEhznJAA)

Comment: You should consider how chart.js plugin types are usually implemented: there's no change to `ChartConfiguration`, but there are *additions* to the interfaces [`PluginOptionsByType`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/api/interfaces/PluginOptionsByType.html#interface-pluginoptionsbytype-ttype) and/or [`ChartDatasetProperties`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/api/interfaces/ChartDatasetProperties.html).  ...

Comment: ... A plugin type file simply (re)declares those interfaces (into the module "chart.js") and they become effective through [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html), see the [typings](https://github.com/kurkle/chartjs-plugin-gradient/blob/v0.6.1/types/index.d.ts) for chartjs-plugin-gradient.

Comment: @kikon ok I see what you are saying ... And so if I understand correctly the declaration merging happens when the chartjs-plugin-gradient is imported.  Experimenting with the code seems to confirm this.  So if clients want to use the plugin with support for it in `ChartConfiguration` all they need to do is import `chartjs-plugin-gradient`  (Even if the library has already registered it) and that will perform the type merging ...

Comment: Yes, I think the types are merged by *importing* the plugin library which in turn includes its type definitions. But taking into consideration that *all* typescript runs before *any* javascript has run, I don't think registration (which is a javascript function call) may come before type merging (and probably has nothing to do with types)

Comment: @kikon I think you are right.  I tried adding type support by just doing the important and without registering the plugin, and type support within `ChartConfiguration` is still added, so like you are saying the type support is added independent of the call to register the plugin.

Comment: "_the type support is added independent of the call to register the plugin_": indeed, as soon as a TS file containing an interface declaration merge is imported, the merge is effective, irrespective of actual JS code.